# javascript code editor

Tags: javascript

I need to write a browser-based simple code editor that would highlight errors such as unclosed parentheses, code completion etc.

my question is - which tools would you recommend using to implement this? pure js? gwt?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://codemirror.net/ - Are you are looking for something like this? The editor embedded in the book Eloquent JavaScript was excellent. (CodeMirror is created by Marijn Haverbeke, the author of [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net))

Answer (score 5):

You should check out Cloud9 IDE ( http://c9.io/ ) which uses Ace. You can also embed Ace in your site ( http://ace.ajax.org/ )

Ace (from Ajax.org Cloud9 Editor) is a standalone code editor written in JavaScript. The goal is to create a web-based code editor that matches and extends the features, usability, and performance of existing native editors such as TextMate, Vim, or Eclipse. It can be easily embedded in any web page and JavaScript application. Ace is developed as the primary editor for Cloud9 IDE and as the successor of the Mozilla Skywriter project.

Features

- Syntax highlighting.
- Auto indentation and outdent.
- An optional command line.
- Work with huge documents (100,000 lines and more are no problem).
- Fully customizable key bindings including VI and Emacs modes.
- Themes (TextMate themes can be imported).
- Search and replace with regular expressions.
- Highlight matching parentheses.
- Toggle between soft tabs and real tabs.
- Displays hidden characters.
- Highlight selected word.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you start with Doug Crawford's [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), which is in JavaScript. It not only parses the file for syntax errors but also identifies code that is legal but dangerous or error prone.

Comment: Perhaps the question isn't clear. I got confused the first time too. I think he's looking to write a code editor, not use one.

Comment: I was answering the "highlight errors" part. Perhaps both of our answers together is a complete answer.

Comment: thanks guys! vijay - where would you use jQuery rather than js in such an app?

Answer (score -2):

Javascript with a little bit of JQuery should be just fine. GWT is better used with bigger projects. You are better off with the flexibility of directly writing JS.